# Libraries like universal image loader for iphone-(Using an android library in both monotouch and monodroid)

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, universal-image-loader

I used monodroid to develop an application for android. Now, I want to develop the application by monotouch for iphone. In android application i used Universal Image Loader to show downloaded images in list view's image view , gallery view and etc.
Now question is this, Is there any libraries like universal image loader that can use this library for iphone's app?
Or whether xamarin give feature to using a library in monotouch and monodroid application both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MonoTouch, the library I most often see used for image loading and caching is the image loader within the MonoTouch.Dialog project.

Others are available, including there's a cache in my library, mvvmcross ... although now I'm tempted to look at using Universal Image Loader instead!

Comment: OK.Do you have some samples or tutorials for the libraries for monotouch?

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad mituni9az in estefade koni : https://github.com/hirohisa/ImageLoaderSwift , ya in : https://github.com/hirohisa/ImageLoader